# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in this program?

Tags: c, pointers, string, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to set the values of M and N in this program to whatever is parsed from a string that this C program receives on it's command line. However, I'm getting a segmentation fault whenever I run the code. I'm new to the concept of pointer in C, so I know it's something there.

The code is supposed to work as follows:

./a.out -1,12

Prints:

1, 12

Thanks for any help!

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    void getnumber(char *toTest, int *a, int *c);

    int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
    {

            int a, c, curr; 

            a = 1;
            c = 1;
            curr = 1;

            if ( argv[1][0] == '-' )
            {
                    curr = 2;
                    getMandNValues(argv[1], &a, &c);
            }

            printf("%d, %d\n", a, c);
            return 0;
    }


    void getMandNValues(char *src, int *a, int *c)
    {

            char aString[sizeof src];
            char bString[sizeof src];

            int i = 0;

            while((aString[i] = &src[i+1]) != ',')
                    ++i;

            aString[i] = '\0';

            int j = 0;

            while((bString[j] = &src[i + 2]) != '\0')
            {
                    ++j;
                    ++i;
            }

            bString[j] = '\0';

            *a = atoi(aString);
            *c = atoi(bString);
    }
```

The compiler output is:

```
/tmp/foo.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/foo.c:18: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘getMandNValues’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/tmp/foo.c:18: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘getMandNValues’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/tmp/foo.c: In function ‘getMandNValues’:
/tmp/foo.c:34: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
/tmp/foo.c:41: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Comment: I seriously hope you didn't actually indent (or rather not) all your code like that...

Comment: Someone should leave a comment about the lengths of aString and bString.

Comment: the size of aString and bString will always be 4 in your code. They will not be the length of the passed in src string.

Comment: Where does the debugger say that the segfault occurs?

Comment: @bk1e : I'm sure on the non-pointers passed as pointers.  segfault means "illegal pointer".

Answer (score 3):

Did not look at everything but you need the address of the vars for this call.

```
getMandNValues(argv[1], &a, &c);
```

I don't know what compiler you are using but I would not ignore the warning it must have displayed at compile.  (If you are not using the highest level of warning you should.)

---

Looking some more there is another problem

```
while((aString[i] = &src[i+1]) != ',')
   ++i;
```

Seems strange (and wrong).  I would do this:

```
int index=0;
do
{
  aString[index] = src[index+1];
  index++;
} while (str[index] != ',')
```

---

here is another problem

```
char aString[len(src)];
char bString[len(src)];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getMandNValues(argv[1], a, c);
```

should be

```
getMandNValues(argv[1], &a, &c);
```

Answer (score 1):

you should pass &a and &c to the function, for one.

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing `getnumber` and `getMandNvalues`.

You've supplied a prototype for `getnumber` but no definition of that function. You supplied a definition of `getMandNvalues` but no prototype before you call this function.

Calling a function with no prototype in scope is legal. The compiler assumes it returns `int` and all arguments are `int`. Neither of these is true in this case.

**Correct your prototype**

Answer (score 0):

You pass the int a and int c to the function that expects the int* a and int* c

instead of using

```
getMandNValues(argv[1], a, c);
```

, try

```
getMandNValues(argv[1], &a, &c);
```